# 1996 Mustang GT won't start with shifter in Park, but will start in Neutral

Tags: engine, electrical, ford, automatic-transmission, mustang

I just had this weird problem today. The engine will turn fine, but won't start with shifter in Park. Once started in Neutral the motor runs fine with no hesitations. Battery is strong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The range switch doesn't think the car is in park. On Fords theres an adjustable cable if you look on the driver side of the transmission there will be lever with a cable attached. Sometimes the clip on the cable fails. if the cable is OK pull the lever all the way into park and it should start. If it doesn't you probably need a new range switch.

[image]

Comment: @ Ben Thanks a lot for your answer. Also, where would the range switch be located exactly? I did some searching but couldn't find any info for the Mustang.

Comment: @Steve Updated with a picture may not be 100% accurate but it'll show what you're looking for.